# Cursor over NSView placed over NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I have a semi-transparent `NSView` subclass that acts as a kind of tooltip. When the tooltip is drawn on the screen it draws on top of a form and so it covers a couple of `NSTextField`'s.

When I hover the mouse over the tooltip at the spots where a NSTextField exists, the cursor changes to the input style cursor.

How can I prevent the cursor from changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlapping views are not really supported very well in Cocoa and the behaviour is undefined.

Instead, your tooltip view should be in its own borderless window, large enough to contain your view. The tooltip window should be a child window of the main window it's attached to. To make a window a child of another window, you use the `addChildWindow:ordered:` method of `NSWindow`.

Child windows are attached to the parent window and will move with their parent window when the parent window moves. If you just open a new window without making it a child window, it will be "left behind" if the other window is moved.

To make a borderless window, pass `NSBorderlessWindowMask` as the `styleMask` to the `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:` method of `NSWindow`.

Comment: Will it work even if the tooltip is attached to an element inside a NSScrollView?

Comment: It's your responsibility to manage the window. You'd need to listen to the various resize/scroll notifications and update the window accordingly.